# difference between init and control script?

Tags: linux, bash, init

I am writing a script, for the first time. I followed few examples and I have my init script and then a control script that uses the loop option, to create a copy if itself and start the final application.

My questions are:

**1.** What is the difference between an init script and a control script? Why is better to implement them separately?

**2.** Why do I need to create a copy of the control script to start the application (loop), why not do it directly with the control script? What are the benefits of doing it like this?

**3.** How could I improve my scripts? For example I don't know if using directly kill -9 is the best option, I have read few comments against it..

My init script is very basic:

```
#!/bin/bash
APPCTL="/home/app/appctl"
APPBIN="/home/app/app.cpp"

if [ ! -x "$APPCTL" -o ! -f "$APPBIN" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: app is missing or is not executable" >&2
    exit 1
fi
if [ "$1" = "stop" -o "$1" = "restart" ]; then
    echo "Stopping app"
    "$APPCTL" stop
fi
if [ "$1" = "start" -o "$1" = "restart" ]; then
    echo "Starting app"
    "$APPCTL" start
fi
```

My control script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
APP_DIR="/home/app"
APP_CTL="$APP_DIR/appctl"
APP_BIN="$APP_DIR/app.cpp"
APPCLT_PID="/var/run/appctl.pid"
OWN_PID=$$

case "$1" in
   start)
        if [ -f "$APPCLT_PID" ]; then
            PID=$(cat "$APPCLT_PID")
        fi
        if [ "$PID" != "" ]; then
            COMM=$(ps --pid "$PID" ho comm)
            if [ "$COMM" == "appctl" ]; then
                echo "Already runnning..."
                exit 0
            fi
        fi
        "$APP_CTL" loop 2>&1 &
        ;;
   stop)
    if [ -f "$APPCLT_PID" ]; then
        PID=$(cat $APPCLT_PID)
        if [ "$PID" != "" ]; then
           kill -9 "$PID"
        fi
        rm -f "$APPCLT_PID"
    fi
    for pid in $(pgrep -f $APP_BIN); do
        kill $pid
    done
    ;;
   loop)
    echo $OWN_PID > "$APPCLT_PID"
    cd "$APP_DIR"
    while true; do
       nice -n 10 "$APP_BIN" > /dev/null 2>&1
        sleep 5
    done
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's better to implement them separately?  On Debian-based platforms (which it vaguely looks like maybe you are asking about) the most common implementation model seems to be to have one script for both purposes.

Comment: The reasons to not use `kill -9` are [well documented](http://iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter).  Your program should shut down cleanly even when sent a regular `SIGSTOP`; using `SIGTERM` bypasses any possible shutdown signal handler.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I am very new in this so I followed few examples I had in the system I am using. I will kill my processes with a more gentle way :)

What I am wondering now is if there is some way to unify the scripts for both applications in C/C++ and PHP, because currently I need to execute php with command php-cgi. Is there any way to add at the beginning of the script #/path/php-cgi so I don't need to write different script for different programming languages?

Comment: That sounds like a completely unrelated question.  Go [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).